# "unknown encoding name" when using gem command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cygwin, codepages, mintty

On Windows 10 using the Cygwin environment, I get the following error:

```
 $ gem list
 ERROR:  Loading command: list (ArgumentError)
      unknown encoding name - CP20127
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
      undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I have

```
 $ gem --version
 3.0.    
 $ ruby --version
 ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-cygwin]
 $ echo $LANG
 en_GB
```

running in a mintty terminal (version 3.1.6)

I haven't used the *gem* command for months. It did work once, but of course any of the components involved, have been updated in between several times. I don't know where the encoding CP20127 comes from. It does not look like a valid encoding name or Windows code page name to me, but it indeed seems to be Windows is using:

```
$ chcp
Aktive Codepage: 20127
```

I never fiddled around with the code page and I wonder where this setting could come from, and why it could affect my *gem* command.

**UPDATE**

I tried the following:

```
chcp 850
```

After this, `gem list` works. Hence, the culprit was the codepage setting. Now my question: Since I never explicitly set the codepage anywhere, what could the most likely reason be for the incorrect codepage setting?

**UPDATE 2**

I found meanwhile that CP20127 is set by mintty, while in another terminal (say, the normal Windows command console, or the [conemu](https://conemu.github.io/) console, my shell has CP850. I also found that CP65001 (Unicode Codepage) does not break the `gem` command.

JörgWMittag pointed out in his comment, that CP20127 is the ASCII codepage, so I wonder why the `gem` command does not work with it. In other words: Is it a bug in `gem` (because it should not bail out with this CP), or is it a bug in `mintty` (because it sets this CP), or do I miss something else?

Comment: "It does not look like a valid encoding name or Windows code page name to me" – CP20127 is the codepage for ASCII.

Comment: @Thanks a lot. I googled for this CP, but did not find anything for it; that's why I assumed that it would not exist.